# Include folder does not appear in my Qt project tree

Tags: qt, cmake, include

[image]

Despite using `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, my `include` folder does not appear on my project tree.
Because of this, `MOC` can't find my headers (containing the `Q_OBJECT` macro) and compile them, thus producing errors such as:

```
error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall DashboardClient::metaObject(void)const
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add my header file in my `CMake` sources:

```
SET(executable_SOURCES
    source/main.cpp
    source/dashboard_client.cpp
    include/dashboard_client.h
)
```